# Plugin to respond to multiple group events

Tags: php, joomla

I've to create a plugin which should respond to events that do not belong to the group specified in the plugin installation file.

So I need an advice on how to accomplish this without creating separate plugins.

If I create a new plugin group(by specifying a new group in the xml file), is it possible do this? Really, I tried doing that, but without any success. I tried even registering events manually.
What I got is this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

global $mainframe;

$mainframe->registerEvent('onAuthenticate', 'plgGroupNamePluginName');
$mainframe->registerEvent('onAfterDisplayTitle', 'plgGroupNamePluginName');

class plgGroupNamePluginName extends JPlugin {

    function plgGroupNamePluginName(& $subject, $config) {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    function onAfterDisplayTitle(& $article, & $params, $limitstart=0) {
        // TODO: Code
    }

    function onAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response) {
        // TODO: Some business logic
    }

}
```

I feel that the Joomla documentation is not clear on this things, or maybe I am missing something.

If something is not clear, just let me know.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you don't need the `registerEvent` calls.  It will do that automatically for you if you extend `JPlugin`. (And hence no need for `global $mainframe;`)

Secondly, don't use PHP4 style constructors.  J! has the object class that'll make that work for you:

```
function __construct(& $subject, $config) {
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
}
```

Now, as for your question, groups only matter when loading the plugins.  They do not matter for execution.  So if you create it as a system plugin, it will always be loaded and will respond to all events you have methods for.  There's really no need to create your own group unless you want to control when it's instantiated...

Does that make sense?

Comment: I will try doing that as soon as possible and let you know the result.

Comment: It's working.. but with one problem.

As you said, I created a new system plugin with onAfterRoute and onAuthenticate functions.

onAfterRoute is working fine, but the onAuthenticate is not working.
So just to check what you said, I added onLoginUser function and that is working just fine.

I think that the problem with onAuthenticate is something related to the calling order. I got the Joomla auth plugin activated, because I don't want to handle the auth process, but I just want to do some business logic before logging in the user. That's why I added the onAuthenticate function in my plugin.

Comment: I think that my onAuthenticate function is not really getting called or is called after Joomla auth plugin's onAuthenticate function.

Is there any way to make my onAuthenticate function to be called before Joomla auth plugin's onAuthenticate function?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication plugins are one of the very few exceptions - they must be done seperately.  Authentication plugins are run BEFORE any system plugins so by the time the system plugin runs it is too late.

Plugins are based on the Dispatcher/Listener pattern.  The plugin when loaded tells the "Dispatcher" what events it is interested in being informed about and what function to call when that event occurs.  On the flipside, Joomla tells the Dispatcher when events occur and sends it some data that may be needed for processing the event and the Dispatcher tells the registered listeners.

Groups [System, User, Content] are merely collections of events a listener is interested in - Joomla! will load different groups at different times.  So listeners from the System group are always loaded after authentication - listeners from the Content group will only be loaded if there is content, etc.

"The Dispatcher" is generally true - but Joomla! does allow for multiple dispatchers.  Before the user is authorized, a special authentication dispatcher is loaded which is thrown away and replaced by the "real" dispatcher after authentication.